# Bash vs python for unix-related tasks

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, linux-mint, python

Even with experience in higher level programming languages, I am struggling with Bash to automate tasks (as a newbie of Unix - Linux Mint). The language is very powerful, but the learning curve is too steep. Hence, I am thinking to move completely to python for scripting (python is preinstalled on Linux Mint).

My preference is to go for readability and testability (python) vs conciseness and elegance (Bash).

Can you list a few most important reasons why using python vs scripts will *not" be justifiably/possible in O/S related tasks.

Comment: I don't think possible vs non-possible is a concern. Python can do just fine things bash can, probably even better because you have more control over how files are opened, file descriptors, etc. Portability may be a concern, as not all systems have switched to Python 3. Speed might be another concern, Python can be slow to start up and of course can't compete in speed with C programs like say `sed`. But otherwise, I'd say just use what you're comfortable with, and what gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"automating tasks" is a bit broad. A lot of typical sysadmin tasks can be stored in very simple shell scripts, or single commands, where a "real" language would be too high level to be practical. That's where the name "shell" comes from - you are comfortably seated inside it, but also caught. There is no perl shell or python shell - I don't even know why, exactly.

The shell(s) let you integrate **other interpreters** very easily: shebang for executables, and explicit call with a string ("one liner") or file ("named script").

> readability and testability vs conciseness and elegance

You can have that all with either langauge **depending on the specific problem**. The question is not `(python vs. perl) vs. bash`, but rather which "hammer" to use for which "nail".

From the comment:

> Speed might be another concern, Python can be slow to start up...

Again, everything depends on the specific task/algorithm. But speed is a concern always, because a "harmless" looking loop can take 10 or 100 times longer if you do it just somehow.

> I'd say just use what you're comfortable with, and what gets the job done.

I agree if this means: before you write a script, you have to decide:

1. How to do it efficiently? (and portable, and maintainable, and elegant, and ...)
2. What tools do I like to use? (am I good at?)

It should match up.

If not: then you do a hack in *your* language or you learn a new topic in the *other* language.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: I just do not understand why my q was put on hold? Is it because the unix crowds cannot easily take a question which suggests that bash may not be as readable and testable as other languages? Bizarre.. looks like religious zeal!

Comment: exactly. religious zeal plus reputation points hamstering. If you are unprepared it is highly confusing. You saved my day. Because of the human feedback, not the 15 points - but hey thanks!

Comment: @afora377, because the (un)readability and other such features of programming languages are highly subjective. It's hard to have objectively good answers when it's basically about opinions and preferences.

Comment: @rastafile, closing questions doesn't grant any reputation. It also doesn't stop anyone from upvoting the question or the already existing answers.

Comment: Well, that's your excuse - everything in this life (apart from computer languages, logic and math) comes with shades of grey. You guys may be great developers but you live in your own universe. And hence your psychological biases show every time you feel threatened. It's a sad and insecure life really.

Comment: And to respond to your point - I was not asking for a proof of what's readable or not. I was exactly asking for people's opinion. A subjective experiences they can share. You are just so low on EQ really. And nobody cares about reputational points here except for you. A sad score of success in somebody's life I suppose